# Returning constant character pointer from a function

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, const-pointer

Does

```
const char * const getName () const
{ 
   return name ;
}
```

means that `getName()` returns a constant pointer to a constant character? Since the function is constant , it would not modify any of its arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example,

```
const char * const getName() const { return name; }
```

most likely returns a constant pointer to a constant nullterminated character **string** (i.e. to the first character in such a string). Technically it's just a pointer to a `char`. But such pointers are treated as pointers to nullterminated strings by e.g. `cout`.

Since the method is declared `const` it cannot directly modify ordinary non-`mutable` members, but it can modify data pointed to by members that are pointers. This means that technically it *can* modify things that are regarded as parts of the object that it's called on, if those things are declared `mutable` or are pointed to by pointers. However, the common *convention* for a `const` method is that even if it does some internal changes such as updating a cache, it will not change the object's externally visible state, i.e. from an outside view it will not appear to have changed the object.

For C++,

- Preferentially use a string class such as `std::string`, in particular to avoid problems with lifetime management of dynamically allocated memory.
- Don't use `get` prefixes, since in C++ they only add more to read (e.g., would you write `getSin(x)*getCos(x)`?). More generally, name things such that the *calling* code reads like English prose! :-) You may look at it as designing a little language.
- As a general rule, don't add `const` on the top level of a return value, since that prevents move optimizations.

Also, conventionally one uses a member naming convention such as `name_` (note that the underscore is at the *end*, not at the *front*, to avoid conflict with a C naming convention) or `myName`.

Thus, ordinary in C++ that function would be coded up as

```
string name() const { return name_; }
```

assuming that `string` is available unqualified in the non-global namespace where this definition resides (which is my preference).

Answer (score 4):

It means that `getName()` returns a constant pointer to a constant character and it will not modify any non-mutable class members inside the function body.
Note that class members declared as [mutable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4h2h0ktk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) can be still modified in this function.